# Ruby on Rails - Why validades_presence_of only work at create and not at update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm having a problem with validations at rails, i have a parameter call **propose** that cannot be blank, when I try to create it work, but when update do not, this is my validations:

```
class Propose < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :propose, :date, :meeting_type


end
```

For some reason, this only works when a object is create, then **propose** cannot be blank, but if I try update for empty it works when should not. I tried this solution, but did not work as well:

```
validates_length_of :propose, :minimum => 1, allow_blank: false
```

In both cases, my rspec returns this

```
     Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to be_empty
   expected `"{\"id\":508,\"propose\":\"\",\"business_id\":442,\"date\":\"2017-05-24T00:00:00.000-03:00\",\"meetin...\":\"2017-05-24T14:13:42.120-03:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-05-24T14:13:42.120-03:00\",\"status\":0}".empty?` to return true, got false
```

This is the test:

```
it "Should not be able to update propose because propose is blank" do
      @propose = Fabricate(:propose, company: @current_user.return_company)
      put :update, propose_id: @propose.id, propose: ''
      expect(response.body).to be_empty
      expect(response.status).to eq(422)
end
```

This is my controller:

```
def update
    begin
      propose = Propose.find(params[:propose_id])
      propose.update_attributes(update_params)
      render(json: propose.to_json, status: :ok)
    rescue => e
      render(json: {error: e.message}, status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
private
def update_params
    params.permit(:propose, :date, :meeting_type, :status)
end
```

So, that is the problem, **propose** cannot be blank when update or create, but the validations appears only to work for create. I know that I can use something like:

```
raise "empty propose" if params[:propose].empty?
```

But I want to use rails methods if possible to the code don't be fill with manually validations when there is a way to do using rails already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could use "dangerous" `.update!` which raises an exception if the record is invalid:

```
def update
  begin
    propose = Propose.find(params[:propose_id])
    propose.update!(update_params)
    render(json: propose.to_json, status: :ok)
    # Never use rescue without an exception type!
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    render(json: {error: e.message}, status: :unprocessable_entity)
  end
end
```

This is not a good practice since exceptions should be used for exceptional events. Not the normal application flow.

Instead use the safe `.update` method and check the return value:

```
def update
  propose = Propose.find(params[:propose_id])
  if propose.update(update_params)
    render(json: propose.to_json, status: :ok)
  else
    render(json: { errors: propose.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity)
  end
end
```

Comment: Your should also name your model Proposal - which is the noun form, not propose which is the verb form. Models should be named after things - not actions.

Comment: `e` is not valid in your example of  "safe" `update` method

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `update_attributes` but never checking its return value. Since it looks like you're expecting an error to be raised, you should use `update_attributes!` (with an exclamation mark at the end) instead.

Note that it is advisable to rescue only from those errors you're actually expecting to be thrown. In this case, you should `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e`.

Alternatively, you can also use the [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) method to execute error handling in a separate method. This is helpful if your error handler is more complex, for example because it has its own `respond_to` block.

Comment: Maybe mention the Error (`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`) that will be raised since rescuing `Exception` is not the best idea.

Comment: Good point! Thanks for the hint, I added some additional explanation to that point.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `response.body` will never be `empty` based on what you have and generally shouldn't be as it offers no context to the situation.

Secondly you are not checking that `update_attributes` returned `false` you are just returning the object. That object is in an invalid state and does not reflect the persisted object since validation failed.

`update_attributes` will call `assign_attributes` before `save` so the in memory `propose` will reflect the new assignment with `propose.propose` being blank but that is not actually what is stored in the database.

Consider changing update to

```
def update
  begin
    propose = Propose.find(params[:propose_id])     
    if propose.update_attributes(update_params)
      render(json: propose.to_json, status: :ok)
    else
      # modify this portion as you see fit
      render(json: {error:{errors: propose.errors.full_messages}}.to_json,status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
end
```

If you want an Error to be raised as your initial intent implies then use

```
# expanded based on @ma_il's answer
def update
  begin
    propose = Propose.find(params[:propose_id])
    propose.update_attributes!(update_params) #notice the bang (!)
    render(json: propose.to_json, status: :ok)
  # notice we are only rescuing ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid rather than 
  # Exception which is considered poor form and could expose information in the json that you don't intend
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e 
    render(json: {error: e.message}, status: :unprocessable_entity)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Quoting Rails documentation on `update` a.k.a `update_attribute`

> Updates a single attribute and saves the record. This is especially
>   useful for boolean flags on existing records. Also note that
>
> - Validation is skipped.
> - Callbacks are invoked.
> - updated_at/updated_on column is updated if that column is available.
> - Updates all the attributes that are dirty in this object.
>
> This method raises an ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError if the attribute
>   is marked as readonly.
>
> So there's that, `update` skips the validation steps, if you want to validate your models either call `valid?` yourself or use `save` instead of `update`.

Comment: This is incorrect  `update-attributes` with an "s" runs validations